# C# Treeview help

Tags: c#, treeview

If I have a treeview being imported into my main program from a dll event.  How can I think assign this full Treeview to aTreeview control within my app?

I have the Treeview object from the dll, but I can't figure out how to assign it to the control?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the instance to the `Controls` collection of the `Form`/`Control` it will be hosted on.

Comment: Would that be the Form1.Designer.cs?

Comment: @darren young: No, you can do it anywhere after InitializeComponents() has been called.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but I am still unsure.  I am quite new to C#.  So if I have the Treeview control, call it Treeview 1, would I assign as such Treeview1 = _tv;  With _tv being the new Treeview?

Comment: @darren young: It should be as simple as `Controls.Add(yourtreeviewfromanotherplace);`  You could create a reference to it, if needed, but it is not necessary for it to be added to the host control.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you should be able to add it to your toolbox and then just drag it onto the canvas/ form. (right-click in toolbox and select elements)

hth

Mario

Comment: He mentions he has an instance, not a type. The type I expect to be of `TreeView` anyways.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I overlooked the 'event' part! My solution only works for types - as you pointed out!